# Notepad++ (ver.: 6.7.8.2) functionlist. Commentaries between head and body dysfunction

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have been searching for a Solution on the Web and here with no luck. I have a Problem with how the function list in Notepad++ works, I was hoping it can be fixed in the functionList.xml...

**The function list does NOT list a function, if there is a commentary between the functionhead and the function Body**, as shown below.

```
void main()
//------- commentary here
{...}
```

If there is no commentary at this position the function list works fine. But I work with Levelscripts (similar to c++ but less advanced) that have a massive amount of such commentaries, rendering the function list pretty useless. I used to use a **very old** Notepad++ Version with a Function list 2.0 plugin that worked for these scripts. Until now I have used the old Notepad++ Version but it really is not practical any longer.

I have also tried the functionlisting of C++ and C, they have the same issue.

I have created my own UDL for Notepad++, which works fine, I have also edited the functionList.xml which works so far, except it also has the above mentioned Problem. I was hoping that this could be fixed by using regular expressions, because they are used to set how a function is recognized. I have here is what I have made up so far to be used inside the functionList.xml:

```
            <parser id="stef2_morpheurs_script" displayName="stef2_morpheurs_script" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(//.*?$))">
            <function
                mainExpr="^[\t ]*((void|float|vector|string)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)?[\n\s]*\{"
                displayMode="$functionName">
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+[\s]*\("/>
                    <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </parser>
```

This is what I think is the essential part:

```
mainExpr="^[\t ]*((void|float|vector|string)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)?[\n\s]*\{"
```

After several hours of trying and reading about regular expressions I made very little Progress, because my skills with Notepad++ regEx are quite insufficient.

So any tips or suggestions how to Approach this and maybe a Statement if it is even possible to solve this with regular expressions would be highly appreciated.

---

Latest code:

```
^[\t ]*[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]‌​+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)(.*[\n\s]*)*(?!(;))
```

Comment: I wonder if `^[\t ]*((void|float|vector|string)[\s]+)?[\w:]+(\s+\w+)?(\s+|\*\s+|\s+\*\s*)([\w_]+\s*::)?(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+\s*\([^\)\(]*\)?[\r\n\s]*(\/\/.*[\r\n])?\{` will work for you. I tested it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zW8bJ1/1), please check.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast reply, but unfortunately it does not work.
The functionlist appears to NOT abort due to a error, but it does not list any functions at all now. Just the name of the current file is being displayed.

Comment: I have tried several other combinations, the best I have been able to come up with was:
`^[\t ]*[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)(.*[\n\s]*)*(?!(;))`

But even this does not work with notepad++, **I am pretty sure by now that this is intentional or a bug of notepad++**